# Sequential interior is sequentially open

Tags: general-topology

I am following the definitions in the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space).

I am wondering if the sequential interior of a set $S$ is the "biggest" sequentially open subset of $S$. I would expect this to be true, but did not see any prove on the wiki page and was unable to produce one myself. In fact, I can't even proof that $\text {SeqInt }S$ is sequentially open. The problem is that given any sequence that converges to a point $s$ of $\text {SeqInt }S$, I know that the sequence is eventually in $S$. I don't see how this would imply that the sequence is eventually in $\text {SeqInt }S$, as, say, every 4th element of the sequence could be not in $\text {SeqInt }S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the sequential closure $\operatorname{SeqCl}(A)$ of a set $A$ need not be sequentially closed (a space where this does always hold is called Fréchet-Urysohn, see also Wikipedia); in general the sequential closure operator is not "topological" (idempotent). Dually the same holds for sequential interior: it need not be sequentially open.

Look for examples of sequential spaces that are not Fréchet-Urysohn to see concrete examples.

Comment: This book has a bunch of weird spaces to break your brain in, there's probably an example there.  https://www.amazon.com/Counterexamples-Topology-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/048668735X/ref=asc_df_048668735X/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=312165853622&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=3945318848015335408&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9012002&hvtargid=pla-449277484053&psc=1&tag=&ref=&adgrpid=60258872297&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvadid=312165853622&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=3945318848015335408&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9012002&hvtargid=pla-449277484053

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what a misleading name, though I can't think of a better name still.